# How to parse a time value of type UTCTime from string in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, time

This is a follow-up question to [the one I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815742/haskell-how-to-add-minutes-to-current-time-using-data-time) just a little while ago.

I couldn't find a single example (sorry for my Google skills) on the Haskell site which shows how to use the `Data.Time` functions to convert a formatted `String` to `UTCTime` and then be able to add/subtract minutes/seconds from that and convert back the `UTCTime` to formatted `String`.

I am looking for an example that shows how to convert a `String` (e.g. like `"10:20:30"` to `UTCTime` and then add 1000 seconds to that time. How to do this Haskell using the `Data.Time` library without using IO at all?

The type of the function should be `FormatTime -> String -> UTCTime`.

The function should use `TimeLocale` or `FormatTime` as locale/formatting is needed.

There are so many functions in the library and so many types that it just baffling. `readTime`, `TimeLocale`, `ParseTime t`, `NominalDiffTime`, `Time` and what not.

Please do not just point to docs on [the Haskell site](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/libraries/time-1.1.4/Data-Time-Format.html#t%3AFormatTime). Most of the docs there are just a dump of type signatures from the source code, without almost any examples. Sorry if this is coming as rant, but I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out something from those docs.

Compare this to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) on time. So many beautiful examples.
Thank god, there is SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import Data.Time

timeFormat = "%H:%M:%S"
understandTime = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale timeFormat

time :: UTCTime
time = understandTime "10:30:20"
```

---

```
λ> time
1970-01-01 10:30:20 UTC
```

Let's break down what's going on:

- `timeFormat` is simply a string, describing how we expect the time to be passed to us.
- we partially apply [`parseTimeOrError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:parseTimeOrError), using [`defaultTimeLocale`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:defaultTimeLocale) for the locale, and previously defined `timeFormat` for the expected format.
- We now have a `understandTime` function, that can take in a time as a `String`. When using it, we need to explicitly set the expected output type to `UTCTime` (this is what `time :: UTCTime` does). If we were to use `understandTime` within the context of a function that already expects a `UTCTime`, this would be unnecessary (for example `addUTCTime 1000 (understandTime "10:30:20")`)
- We get back `time`. Note that the year, day, month and timezone default to 1970-01-01 and UTC because we do not explicitly read them in `timeFormat`.

Comment: I am getting `Not in scope: 'parseTimeOrError'`, which module to import?

Comment: I imported only `Data.Time`. Your haskell version may be outdated. You safely can replace `parseTimeOrError True` with a call to [`parseTime`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:parseTime) if you don't want to update haskell version.

Comment: With that change I am getting the error: `Couldn't match expected type 'UTCTime' with actual type `Maybe t0'    In the return type of a call of 'understandTime'`

Comment: got it working with `time :: Maybe UTCTime`, if you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: answer is valid haskell code, using ghc 8.0.1. I'd rather keep the up-to-date code on SO. `parseTime` is documented as outdated.

Comment: fair enough but then please mention that it will work only with ghc 8.0.1. in the answer. It may not work with future ghc also.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `True` argument?

Comment: Weather to accept or not arguments with leading/trailing white spaces.